# Best way to convert an array of integers to a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

In Java, I have an array of integers. Is there a quick way to convert them to a string?

I.E. `int[] x = new int[] {3,4,5}`
x toString() should yield "345"

Comment: So `{3, 45}` also yields `"345"`? You sure you want to do this? You may want to step back and rethink your design through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplest performant approach is probably StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : array) {
  builder.append(i);
}
String text = builder.toString();
```

If you find yourself doing this in multiple places, you might want to look at [Guava's `Joiner` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) - although I don't believe you'll be able to use it for primitive arrays. EDIT: As pointed out below, you can use [`Ints.join`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) for this.

Comment: Wow, I am lucky, I found that your answer to my question is just your 10000th answer in Stackoverflow,am i right? Congrats!

Comment: I have up-voted your answer. But just a curious? What is more costly (time consuming)? StringBuilder.append(int) or y = y*10 + x; ? I know the primitives will work only till the Integer.MAX_VALUE, but if we always have less than that result, then what would be better?

Comment: Guava's Joiner won't work for int primitives (it works with Objects), but Ints.join("", intArray) will: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html

Answer (score 7):

```
   int[] x = new int[] {3,4,5};
   String s = java.util.Arrays.toString(x).replaceAll("[\\,\\[\\]\\ ]", "")
```

*Update*

For completeness the Java 8 Streams solution, but it isn't pretty (libraries like [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) would be shorter and faster):

```
String s = IntStream.of(x)
  .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this - you have to `import java.util.Arrays` and then -

```
String temp = Arrays.toString( intArray ).replace(", ", "");
String finalStr = temp.substring(1, temp.length()-2);
```

Where intArray is your integer array.

Comment: That yields "[3,4,5]", not "345"

Comment: @Landei - yeah saw that.. Try now. Have edited the answer now

Comment: That's going to give "3 4 5" now instead of "345".

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Yep. Sorry, replace method is adding a space. Edited again. Thanks.

Comment: @didxga - yes, its surely tricky and within two lines of code. Admit I got it from this link if you need more info - http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread14183.html

Comment: Personally I'd rather use my five lines of simple code than two lines of code which have already proved themselves relatively hard to get right :)

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuffer str =new StringBuffer();
for(int i:x){  
str.append(i);
}
```

You need to read all once at least.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] dice = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
    String string = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        string = string + dice[i];
    }

    System.out.print(string);   

}
```

This is another way you can do it. Basically just makes a for-loop that accesses every element in the integer array and adds it to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Integer Value :" +convertIntToString(new int[]{3,4,5}));

  }

  public static String convertIntToString(int intArray[]) {
    List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        listInteger.add(intArray[i]);
    }

    Object o = listInteger;

    return String.valueOf(o).replace("[", "").trim().replaceAll(", ","").trim().replaceAll("\\]","").trim();
  }
```

Comment: I have made use of list here

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Integer Value :" +convertIntToString(new int[]{3,4,5}));
}

public static String convertIntToString(int intArray[]) {
    List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        listInteger.add(intArray[i]);
    }

    Object o = listInteger;

    return String.valueOf(o).replace("[", "").trim().replaceAll(", ","").trim().replaceAll("\\]","").trim();
}
```

Comment: Please don't (badly) copy-paste other answers into your own. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16811343/635608)