# How to remove Trailing White space in Queue/Priority Queue JAVA

Tags: java, queue

```
public class StreamingIntegers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanin = new Scanner(System.in);
        PriorityQueue<Integer> sorted_num = new PriorityQueue<>();
        while (true) {
            String numbers = scanin.nextLine();
            if (numbers.equals("END")) {
                break;
            } else {
                String[] tokens = numbers.split(" ");
                for (String token : tokens) {
                    sorted_num.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
                }
            }
        }
        while (!sorted_num.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(sorted_num.remove() + " ");
        }
        scanin.close();
    }
}
```

[image: PHOTO OF RESULT WHEN USING PROGRAM]

How can I remove that little white space on the end?

Comment: Please use text rather than an image. The output could have been pasted into the question and formatted like code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728563/56778

Comment: It is customary to accept the answer you liked best

Answer (score 2):

I would switch to putting the space in front, after the first pull:

```java
System.out.print(sorted_num.remove());
while (!sorted_num.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(" " + sorted_num.remove());
}
```

This doesn't require a condition check in each line

if there is a possible that you get an empty collection, you guard it:

```java
if (sorted_num.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Nothing to sort here!");
} else {
    System.out.print(sorted_num.remove());
    while (!sorted_num.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(" " + sorted_num.remove());
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In your final `while` loop, check for the size of the `queue` and only append the space if it contained more than one item as follows:

```
System.out.print((sorted_num.size()==1)?sorted_num.remove():sorted_num.remove()+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a prefix which is initially the empty string, and is set to a space in the loop:

```
String prefix = "";
while (!sorted_num.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(prefix + sorted_num.remove());
    prefix = " ";
}
```